# Python: Why can't I import svm?

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn, svm

I am trying to do svm machine learning using scikit-learn. When I type

```
import sklearn
```

No error appears, which means I likely downloaded this package successfully. 
However, when I try

```
from sklearn import svm
```

This error appears:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
from sklearn import svm
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
from .classes import SVC, NuSVC, SVR, NuSVR, OneClassSVM, LinearSVC
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\classes.py", line 1, in <module>
from .base import BaseLibLinear, BaseSVC, BaseLibSVM
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\base.py", line 11, in <module>
from ..preprocessing import LabelEncoder
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
from .data import Binarizer
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\data.py", line 25, in <module>
from ..utils.sparsefuncs import inplace_column_scale
ImportError: cannot import name inplace_column_scale
```

And I checked my directory where I installed python: it shows

```
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm
```

showing that I can find the svm file.

Does that mean there is something lacking in my sklearn file?

PS: I have installed

```
matplotlib, numpy, scipy
```

Comment: @paisanco: duplicate, exactly the same problem.

Comment: Have you tried to install libsvm ?   http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/ I had this problem with weka and installing the lib worked.